# cant make connections betwen uploaded image and template django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to upload a picture for my post model by admin panel but I can't display it in my template, please help
this is my post model
and I get this error please help me
ValueError at /
The 'Img' attribute has no file associated with it.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE ,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='a')
    text = models.TextField(default='a')
    Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null =True)
```

and  for urls.py i used this code:

```
if settings.DEBUG: # new
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and views.py:

```
def post_list(request):
    posts= Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'post/index.html', {'posts': posts})
```

and finally my index.html template:

```
{% for post in posts %}

                    <div class="blog-post-thumb ">
                        <div class="blog-post-image ">
                            <a href="single-post.html ">


                                <img src="{{post.Img.url}}" class="img-responsive " alt="Blog Image ">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog-post-title ">
                            <h3><a href="single-post.html ">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog-post-format ">
                            <span><a href="# "><img src="images/author-image1.jpg " class="img-responsive img-circle ">A</a></span>
                            <span><i class="fa fa-date "></i> published: {{ post.published_date }}</span>
                            <span><a href="# "><i class="fa fa-comment-o "></i>  Comments</a></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog-post-des ">
                            <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
                            <a href="single-post.html " class="btn btn-default ">Continue Reading</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change

```
    posts=Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
```

This To This

```
    posts= Post.objects.all()
```

because you don't have publishdate field in your post model

IF Not Work Then ADD

```
    <a href="single-post.html ">

{% if post.Img %}

            <img src="{{post.Img.url}}" class="img-responsive " alt="Blog Image ">
{% endif %}
    </a>
```

in setting.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

It should work, Because your code work in my Django server .